# Uzbl Browser gets stuck at 10% when Dojo Kit is enabled on the page

Tags: javascript, browser, dojo

My uzbl browser(minimalist browser) gets often stuck at 10% on when the page is dojo kit enabled.

This is the script where it gets stuck up, common.js.

```
if(!dojo._hasResource["wc.render.common"]){ //_hasResource checks added by build. Do not use _hasResource directly in your code.
dojo._hasResource["wc.render.common"] = true;
dojo.provide("wc.render.common");
dojo.require("wc.render.Context");
dojo.require("wc.render.RefreshController");

}
```

It would be great, if someone can point me into the direction I should start looking into. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of resolving this until a new build is released. However said that, the issue can be resolved by bypassing the specific dojo script that causes the issury. As in don't allow this script to load.